# How to stop Mail app from downloading mails from Trash?

Tags: mail.app, macos, gmail, data-transfer, imap

I have lots filters that move junk mails to trash. But Mail app is downloading all mails from trash every time and wasting my bandwidth. How can I configure it to skip trash folder?

Comment: Who is your email provider? This is easily done if it's gmail/google for example, but may not be possible with other providers.

Comment: It is Gmail itself.......